# Query SQL Server to get count data with populate string id another table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, `master` and `transaction`. When in table `transaction` I get populate id with string. And I have a question, how to get count id in table `master` from table `transaction`. I will display sample table and table when I want display.

Table `Master`:

```
IdReferensi   Referensi
-----------------------
   1          Alfa
   2          Beta
   3          Charlie
   4          Delta
   5          Echo
   6          Fanta
   7          Gorilla
```

Table `Transaction`:

```
IdCPAR   NoCPAR   IdReferensi
-----------------------------
   1     NC001       2,5
   2     NC002       1,2,3
   3     NC003       2,3,5
```

Return Table like this

```
IdReferensi   Referensi    Total
--------------------------------
    1         Alfa           1
    2         Beta           3
    3         Charlie        2
    4         Delta          0
    5         Echo           2
    6         Fanta          0
    7         Gorilla        0
```

So, in SQL Server I hope you to help me to create query to display for returning the table from my example. Thanks

Comment: Transactions table should have a row for each `IdReferensi` and `IdCPAR` values pair.

Comment: and i can't to insert another field to table transaction. i just wanna to now how total count id reference in table transaction.thanks.

Comment: that's not a good idea to store IdReferensi as a string because now you should normalize it splitting the string into id list

Comment: And to do it you must be sure at least that your separator is always comma

Comment: yes i know that, but i need to save multiple id. and i will make sure always use comma to separate id

Comment: @achmaddarmawan storing IDs as a string is a **very serious bug**. Use a *separate table to map master and transaction IDs, and just join the three tables. Anything else is only an attempt to **cover up** the bug and fool users and managers

Comment: thank you for your correction, i know i'm wrong to design table like this. may be next project i will create a better design if i must populate id

Comment: @achmaddarmawan fix *this* one. Don't wait for the next project. It's easy to fix it. Handling the problems caused by this will never end. What happens when you try to *update* one of these values? Or remove one? What if you get *more* than 100 transactions? Fixing it takes minutes. So does migrating old data - it can't be that many or you'd have already posted a question about slow performance

Comment: You can extract the individual values using `STRING_SPLIT` which was introduced in SQL Server 2016. `Select IDCPar, value as ReferenceID from Transactions CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(IDReferensi,',')` will return the MasterID-TransactionID pair you need to populate the many-to-many table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your solution but for right now i still busy, may be tomorrow i will try to fix this case. :)

Comment: @achmaddarmawan let's put it this way then: That's a career-limiting bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general disclaimer, you should usually avoid storing CSV data in your tables because it is the epitomy of denormalization.  Instead, store each CSV value on a separate row.

To add to this problem, SQL Server has no built in function like MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET()` which can conveniently search for a string inside a CSV value.  Instead, we have to resort to using several `LIKE` comparisons to assert if a value be contained inside CSV string.

```
SELECT
    m1.IdReferensi,
    m1.Referensi,
    m2.Total
FROM Master m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        t1.IdReferensi,
        COUNT(t2.IdReferensi) AS Total
    FROM master t1
    LEFT JOIN Transaction t2
    ON t2.IdReferensi LIKE t1.IdReferensi + ',%' OR         -- beginning of CSV
       t2.IdReferensi LIKE '%,' + t1.IdReferensi + ',%' OR  -- middle of CSV
       t2.IdReferensi LIKE '%,' + t1.IdReferensi            -- end of CSV
    GROUP BY t1.IdReferensi
) m2
    ON m1.IdReferensi = m2.IdReferensi
```

As a disclaimer, this query will not give reliable results if a given CSV value contains only a single number with no comma present.  If you be worried about this edge case, we could fairly easily add logic to handle this.

## Demo

Comment: i get error : Column 'TReferensi.IdReferensi' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  TableMaster=TReferensi and TableTransacation=TCPAR. thanks...

Comment: Reload your page.

Comment: Just guessing... what if  `IdReferensi` has values for 11 and 1? Wouldn't that mix both values when joining (t1 and t2)?

Comment: What do you mean to "Reload my page" ??? may be you can try to read again my question. thanks @Tim

Comment: It will form like this: 1,11. And I already have "LIKE" condition like this example ::: where IdReferensi LIKE '%,11,%' OR IdReferensi LIKE '%,11' OR IdReferensi LIKE '11,%' OR IdReferensi='11'. Thanks @Petaflop

Comment: it works "http://rextester.com/DSGG64613", but i must edit your query like this ... ON t2.IdReferensi LIKE CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.IdReferensi) + ',%' OR
       t2.IdReferensi LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.IdReferensi) + ',%' OR
       t2.IdReferensi LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.IdReferensi) OR
       t2.IdReferensi = CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.IdReferensi)

Comment: Thank you so much @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The problem with this solution, caused by the bad table design, is that it can't scale. The use of all these `LIKE` calls mean that no index can be used. It will always result in a full table scan of `Transactions`. Performance will get very bad, very quickly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The root cause of the problem is storing CSV data in a column.  Always a sure way to invite problems.

Answer (score 0):

try Cose:

```
 Select IdReferensi,Referensi,
(select count(*) from Transaction where Transaction .IdReferensi like concat('%,', convert(varchar(10), Master.IdReferensi),',%')) as total 
 from Master
```

Comment: Some time ago also I did a query like this and always "0" for the total column, because it is considered string '% IdReference%'. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

[1] Transaction table is just another example of bad design because of fear of [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). This generate such technical debts with string(varchar) columns storing arrays. With a one to many table the solution will be a trivial SELECT COUNT(*) with GROUP BY. But now with this design we have to decompose first arrays into separate values and then we can do grouping and counting.

[2] Bellow can be found my solution:

```
WITH [Transaction]
AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM (VALUES 
            (1, 'NC001', '2,5  '),
            (2, 'NC002', '1,2,3'),
            (3, 'NC003', '2,3,5')
    ) t(ID, NoCPAR, IdReferensi)
), 
DynamicDataNormalization
AS (
    SELECT  v.ID, w.XmlCol.value('(text())[1]', 'INT') AS IntValue
    FROM (
        SELECT  t.ID, CONVERT(XML, '<root><i>' + REPLACE(t.IdReferensi, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i></root>') IdReferensiAsXML 
        FROM    [Transaction] t
    ) v
    OUTER APPLY v.IdReferensiAsXML.nodes('root/i') w(XmlCol)
)
SELECT  ddd.ID, COUNT(*) Cnt FROM DynamicDataNormalization ddd GROUP BY ddd.ID
/*
SELECT  m.IdReferensi, COUNT(*) Cnt 
FROM    [Master] m LEFT JOIN DynamicDataNormalization ddd ON m.IdReferensi = ddd.IntValue
GROUP BY m.IdReferensi
*/
```

**[Demo here for decomposing arrays + grouping + counting](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=67d2568eb3ee1b9246e2960f9970d3d6)**