# Grouping and string concatenate in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I'm new to C# linq.

I have data result as follows,

```
Id | Name   | Code
1  | Go     | GOS
1  | RES    | RECSO
1  | ICS    | ICSO 
2  | Go     | GOS
2  | ICS    | ICSO
```

And I want the result as follows,

```
Id | Name     | Code
1, Go,RES,ICS | GOS,RECSO,ICSO 
2, Go,ICS     | GOS,ICSO
```

Can some one provide the linq query for this, with optimized way, as I have big data set.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some code you've written, some error you've encountered?

Comment: So you want to merge all objects with the same Id into one object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query SQL Server to get count data with populate string id another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073289/query-sql-server-to-get-count-data-with-populate-string-id-another-table)

Answer (score 7):

```
var result = data.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
.Select(s => new {
    Id = s.Key,
    Name = string.Join(",", s.Select(ss => ss.Name)),
    Code = string.Join(",", s.Select(ss => ss.Code)),
});
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it's better to explain how and why this code works. Give some context to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

you need to group your data by `Id` and then use `string.Join` to get comma separated values for `Name` and `Code`

```
var query = from m in Data
            group m by m.Id into grp
            select new {ID = grp.Key
                       ,Name= string.Join(",",grp.Select(g=>g.Name ))
                       ,Code= string.Join(",",grp.Select(g=>g.Code )) };
```

If your data source is EF or LinqtoSQL or any other ORM then use `Data.AsEnumerable()` to force grouping and string concatenation in memory

otherwise It will give Error (in case of EF) or it will generate SQL query for each row (LinqToSQL)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

The LINQ part:

```
List<BeforeData> listBefore = new List<BeforeData>();
Dictionary<int, List<AfterData>> listAfter = listBefore
                .GroupBy(it => it.ID)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(z => new AfterData(z.name, z.code)).ToList());
```

Assuming the classes:

```
public class BeforeData
{
    public int ID;
    public string name, code;

    public BeforeData(int ID, string name, string code)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }
}

public class AfterData
{
    public string name, code;

    public AfterData(string name, string code)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Simplified LINQ